# Text vertical-align not working

Tags: html, css

I'm creating some blocks where the one floats left and the other one floats right and same for the text blocks.

[image: example]

Now what i want to do is vertically align the text but:

```
display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle;
```

Doesn't work and i can't use line-height ( since it isn't a single line ):

```
line-height: value of div;
```

If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great. I've created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hjHNL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a container that has

```
display:table
```

with a table-cell inside it

http://jsfiddle.net/hjHNL/2/

Comment: Thanks mate that worked, i've tried putting that on the p but now since i've put it on a div it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
div#loading {
padding-top:200px;
position: absolute;
top: 35%;
left: 45%;
margin-left: -(Y/2)px;
margin-top: -(Y/2)px;
z-index: 1;
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

You can set the "padding-top" to either px or % but make sure the position is absolute.  It sounds like what you are looking for is to move the text next to the pic down lower for alignment purposes.  I used the above code in a site I designed for a friend.  You can look at the results at:

[Showing alignment of divisions text and images inside a division.](http://www.marknutt.com)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical alignment doesn't like that you are floating it to the right. Put the div in a container, and float that container instead.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method i've found, was adding this to your css class `content_case_copy`

```
.content_case_copy{ 
    width:160px;
position: relative; /*this*/
  top: 50%; /*and this*/
vertical-align:middle;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hjHNL/3/

Comment: you can play with calculating the top that fit your needs (css3): http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-calc-function/